# How can I configure the Android emulator to simulate the Galaxy Nexus?

Tags: android, emulation

What settings for the Android emulator will as closely simulate the characteristics of the Galaxy Nexus as possible?

Comment: there aren't that many settings available on the emulator. Just choose the right amount of memory and the right Android platform.

Comment: The option for hardware back/home:no is kind of important for some applications.

Comment: For different density emulators see here: http://blog.blundell-apps.com/emulator-settings-for-each-android-density/

Answer (score 67):

Here's a try:

- Target: Google APIs - API Level 15
- Skin: Built-in WXGA720

Selecting skin sets the following hardware parameters, leave them as-is:

- Hardware Back/Home: no
- Abstracted LCD density: 320
- Keyboard lid support: no
- Max VM application heap size: 48
- Device ram size: 1024

Galaxy Nexus has no SD card, just internal memory. Distinction between internal and external storage is important and can affect apps. To simulate this:

- add `SD Card support=no` parameter;
- launch emulator with `-partition-size 1024` for 1GB internal memory, or use some other means to increase amount of internal memory available;

If you're working on camera apps, you'll also want to set correct number of cameras, and correct resolution.

[image]

Comment: most of these options are preselected for you

Comment: man i followed these specs and had it working just last week. now when i go to use these settings i keep getting Failed to allocate memory: 8 no matter how much memory i specify for it. what gives.....