# What is a good set of device configurations to test Android app on an emulator?

Tags: android, testing, emulation

Ideally I'd have a heap of physical devices to test on, but in reality I don't have access to devices with all the different characteristics.
I'm targeting Android 1.6-current (4.0.3 at the moment), primarily phones, but also want the app to be at least somewhat usable on tablets.

The configurations I've been usually testing with until now:

- Android 1.6, 320x480 MDPI
- Android 2.2, 480x800 HDPI
- Android 4.0, 480x800 HDPI

(landscape and portrait, with and without network connection)

I'm thinking of a set of configurations that wouldn't be excessively large but still would give good coverage of various devices "out there". What Android emulator configurations would you suggest?

**Update:**

Based on the answers I added this configuration to the list:

- 240x320 LDPI (QVGA skin)

Important to note is that it has **3:4 aspect ratio, different from 3:5 that WVGA has**. If layout is tuned to just barely fit in WVGA, scaling down to QVGA can reveal problems. Good idea to check!

Also, added [simulated Galaxy Nexus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8579988/5821). Just to realize from now on I'll need xhdpi graphics (blurry icons: *not* acceptable!):

- 720x1280, no hardware buttons (WXGA720 skin), no SD card

Comment: -1. If you take a look in the FAQ (http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask) you'll see that these types of questions are not appropriate here.

Comment: @DallaRosa if I change title to "What is a good set of device configuration to test (...)", would that fix it, or do you see other problems with this question?

Comment: Indeed, the title you suggested sounds much better.

Answer (score 0):

What about 240*320 ldpi ? like xperia mini, motorola, cliq

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'd suggest you add LDPI configuration (which is QVGA - 320x240 and has 0.75 density) as far as there are a lot of devices with such screen resolution.

Comment: 2.4% of the devices are LDPI (http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/screens.html), so yes, worth checking if the app is at least semi-usable on small and normal LDPI screens