# Android emulator and Real Android device display issue

Tags: android, android-emulator

Iam a beginner level programmer in android..Now iam developing my own android App. But i dont have many android real device for Testing but a Galaxy Nexus,Galaxy Y and Galaxy Grand and Galaxy Note 2

My problem is , I have created  emulators with similar screen specification of above device where Galaxy nexus and Galaxy y simulator gives exact diplay as like real device when i have run my app.
But Galaxy Grand and Galaxy Note 2 is different from exact device...

Please any one know what is the issue..I used same screen specifcation as it provides in Manufacturer site.

Please any one help me.

Thank you

Comment: You need to explain what is wrong.  How are they different? Screen shots from emulation and real may help..

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the latest version of AVD Manager, you will find a new tab labelled  **Device Definition**.

[How can I configure the Android emulator to simulate the Galaxy Nexus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8566157/how-can-i-configure-the-android-emulator-to-simulate-the-galaxy-nexus)

Here select new Device, and then specify your Screen Size(in) and Resolution(px). You can also specify Size, Screen Ratio and Density besides other things.

[image]

Comment: yes i have tried these thing and its working for nexus and Galaxy y..but not for other phones

Comment: If you dont find your requirement AVI then you have to create AVD as per screen height and width

Comment: yes that's what iam saying..i have manually(entering size and resolution and also pixel densities) created new avd  for all real device ..but its showing exception for two devices